# Sometimes entering an infinite loop in EPA algorithm when calculating contact normal and penetration depth

Tags: c#, 2d, physics, collision, detection

Currently I'm in the middle of developing a 2D physics engine by scratch. And Everything worked well by far. It's object oriented, obviously, with Vectors, matrices and shape classes written from scratch by myself. Collision are not yet that organized, but before that I need to make sure it works.

So for educational purposes I decided to implement GJK algorithm for collision detection and EPA for calculating contact normal. The GJK part works fine. And from the simplex (Triangle since it's 2D) I calculate the closest edge and from there I followed the algorithm. But for some reason which I can't seem to find, in some instances only, the program enters an infinite loop, adding new Vertices to the vertices list, but when I print them they're all the same, And the difference that should be near 0 in EPA gives big results. such as 70.55. So I hope you'll be able to help. Thank you in advance.

```
    public class Collision
    {

    private Shape shape1;
    private Shape shape2;
    public List<Vector2> vertices;
    private Vector2 direction;
    private double TOLERENCE = 2;
    public Vector2 contactNormal;
    public double penetrationDepth;

    private enum State
    {
        NO_INTERSECTION, FOUND_INTERSECTION, STILL_EVOLVING
    }
    private State result = State.STILL_EVOLVING;

    public Collision(Shape shape1, Shape shape2)
    {
        this.shape1 = shape1;
        this.shape2 = shape2;
        vertices = new List<Vector2>();

    }

    public bool isColliding()
    {
        while (result == State.STILL_EVOLVING)
        {
            result = evolveSimplex();
        }

        if (result == State.FOUND_INTERSECTION)
            findContactDetails();
        return result == State.FOUND_INTERSECTION;
    }

    private State evolveSimplex()
    {
        if (vertices.Count == 0)
        {
            direction = shape1.position - shape2.position;
        }

        else if (vertices.Count == 1)
        {
            direction = -direction;
        }
        else if (vertices.Count == 2)
        {
            //ab is the vector from the 1st vertex to the second one
            Vector2 ab = vertices[1] - vertices[0];
            //a0 is the vector from the 1st vertex to the origin
            Vector2 a0 = -vertices[0];
            //Get the direction that is perpendicular to ab in the direction of the origin.
            direction = ab.getPerpendicularUnitVectorTowards(a0);

        }
        else if (vertices.Count == 3)
        {
            //a,b and c are the three vertices
            Vector2 a = vertices[0];
            Vector2 b = vertices[1];
            Vector2 c = vertices[2];

            //lets find cb, ca and c0
            Vector2 cb = b - c;
            Vector2 ca = a - c;
            Vector2 c0 = -c;

            // let's find the perpendicular directions to cb and ca that are towards outside the simplex.
            Vector2 cbPerp = cb.getPerpendicularUnitVectorTowards(c0);
            Vector2 caPerp = ca.getPerpendicularUnitVectorTowards(c0);

            if (cbPerp * c0 < 0)
            {
                vertices.Remove(a);
                direction = cbPerp;
            }
            else if (caPerp * c0 < 0)
            {
                vertices.Remove(b);
                direction = caPerp;
            }
            else
            {
                return State.FOUND_INTERSECTION;
            }
        }

        return addSupport(direction) ? State.STILL_EVOLVING : State.NO_INTERSECTION;
    }
    private bool addSupport(Vector2 direction)
    {
        Vector2 support = shape1.getSupportPoint(direction) - shape2.getSupportPoint(-direction);
        vertices.Add(support);
        return direction * support > 0;
    }

    private void findContactDetails()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Edge closestEdge = findClosestEdge(vertices);

            Vector2 support = shape1.getSupportPoint(closestEdge.normal) - shape2.getSupportPoint(-closestEdge.normal);
            double distance = support * closestEdge.normal;
            Console.WriteLine("difference between the two = " + (Math.Abs(distance - closestEdge.distance)) + " and it's " + (Math.Abs(distance - closestEdge.distance) < TOLERENCE));

            if (Math.Abs(distance - closestEdge.distance) < TOLERENCE)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Contact details found");
                contactNormal = closestEdge.normal;
                penetrationDepth = distance;
                break;

            }

            Console.WriteLine("That was not the closest edge. adding the support to the vertices at index " + closestEdge.index);
            vertices.Insert(closestEdge.index, support);
            Console.WriteLine("The number of vertices now = " + vertices.Count);

            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
            {
                Form1.dots.Add(vertices[i]);
            }

        }
    }

    private Edge findClosestEdge(List<Vector2> simplex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finding closest edge");
        Edge closest = new Edge();
        closest.distance = Double.PositiveInfinity;

        for (int i = 0; i < simplex.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i = " + i);
            int j = i + 1 == simplex.Count ? 0 : i + 1;

            Vector2 a = simplex[i];
            Vector2 b = simplex[j];

            Vector2 edge = b - a;
            Vector2 oa = a;

            Vector2 normal = edge.getPerpendicularUnitVectorTowards(oa);
            double d = Math.Abs(normal * oa);
            Console.WriteLine("distance from origin to edge = " + d);

            if (d < closest.distance)
            {
                closest.distance = d;
                closest.normal = normal;
                closest.index = j;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("returing closest edge " + closest.index + " distance = " + closest.distance);
        return closest;
    }
}
```

And Heres the vector2 class.

```
public class Vector2
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public static Vector2 zeroVector2 = new Vector2(0,0);

    public Vector2(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Vector2 add(Vector2 vector)
    {
        return new Vector2(x + vector.x, y + vector.y);
    }
    public Vector2 subtract(Vector2 vector)
    {
        return new Vector2(x - vector.x, y - vector.y);
    }
    public double dot(Vector2 vector)
    {
        return x * vector.x + y * vector.y;
    }

    public Vector2 multiply(double scalar)
    {
        return new Vector2(x*scalar, y*scalar);
    }
    public double getMagnitude()
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2));
    }
    public void negate()
    {
        x = -x;
        y = -y;
    }
    public Vector2 negated()
    {
        return new Vector2(-x, -y);
    }
    public bool isZeroVector()
    {
        if (x == 0 && y == 0)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public Vector2 normalized()
    {
        return this * (1 / getMagnitude());
    }

    public void normalize()
    {
        x *= (1 / getMagnitude());
        y *= (1 / getMagnitude());
    }


    public static Vector2 operator -(Vector2 vector)
    {
        return vector.negated();
    }

    public static Vector2 operator +(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2)
    {
        return v1.add(v2);
    }
    public static Vector2 operator -(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2)
    {
        return v1.subtract(v2);
    }
    public static double operator *(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2)
    {
        return v1.dot(v2);
    }

    public static Vector2 operator *(Vector2 v, double scalar)
    {
        return v.multiply(scalar);
    }
    public static Vector2 operator *(double scalar, Vector2 v)
    {
        return v.multiply(scalar);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2)
    {
        if (v1.x == v2.x && v1.y == v2.y)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2)
    {
        if (v1.x == v2.x && v1.y == v2.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "x = " + x + " , y = " + y;
    }

    public Vector3 to3DVector()
    {
        return new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    }

    public Matrix toMatrix()
    {
        return new Matrix(new double[2,1]{{x}, {y}});
    }

    public Vector2 rotate(double degrees)
    {
        return (Matrix.getRotationMatrix(degrees) * this.toMatrix()).toVector2();
    }

    public static Vector2 toVector2(Point point)
    {
        return new Vector2(point.X, point.Y);
    }

    public Point toPoint()
    {
        return new Point((int)x,(int)y);
    }

    public Vector2 getPerpendicularUnitVectorTowards(Vector2 direction)
    {
        Vector2 perp =  new Vector2(-y, x) * (1 / getMagnitude());
        Console.WriteLine(perp);
        if (perp * direction < 0)
            perp = -perp;
        return perp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please examine our [intro section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't given us enough to reproduce the error.